# Trouble with maven dependency resolution from behind corporate repo

Tags: java, maven

I haven't ever had this problem before, and I'm not sure why it is occuring now.

In my effective pom file I have the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

yet, when I attempt to perform any mvn-goal I get the following error:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project Could not find
>   artifact kg.apc:jmeter-plugins:jar:1.3.1 in mirror
>   (http://repository.redacted.com/content/groups/public

However I can browse to our company repo and I can see that it is, in fact, there
[image]

I can also browse to my local `.m2` directory on my machine and see that the folder exists there as well.

The strange thing is that when I dig into the directories, there is a resolved POM file but no resolved `.jar` file. I'm really not sure what the issue is, how it is caused, and (just as pertinently) how it's resolved. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First delete the folder on your local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository/kg/` second try to rebuild. If it will not built the second time you need to go to your admins (or whoever is responsible for your Nexus) and ask if they can open it to the internet....

Comment: I've already deleted the contents of my local repository and tried re-resolving dependencies multiple time with no success. I'm planning on talking to our admins tomorrow, but other 3rd party jars download just as expected.

Comment: Those artifact versions might not be in your nexus yet..so they are not downloaded from Central ...